# Normality of residuals in a regression model with a categorical IV

Tags: r, regression, assumptions

I have ran a simple regression with a continuous response variable and a categorical explanatory variable (with 2 levels). I am currently checking that the model meets the assumptions of regression. I produced the following plot:

[image]

I'm aware that I need to check that the residuals are normally distributed. Do I need to check the distribution of residuals at each of the 2 levels of the explanatory variable? Or do I need to check the distribution of all residuals simultaneously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Note that a regression model with only 1 explanatory variable that is categorical and has just 2 levels is equivalent to a t-test; there's nothing wrong with calling it a regression, but it would most commonly be discussed / referred to as a t-test.)

You check the distribution of all the residuals simultaneously.  There are tests for normality, but I'm not a huge fan of them (I listed some in my [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/assumptions-of-generalised-linear-model/32286#32286) to your previous question).  I think the best option is to make a [qq-plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Q_plot).  You can find a really nice version ([qq.plot](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/car/html/qq.plot.html)) in John Fox's [car package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car//index.html).  Among other features, it'll give you a 95% confidence band, which can help you interpret the plot.

On a different note, from looking at your plot, I don't know if you have more data in the second group, but you should also check to ensure you have *homogeneity of variance*.

Comment: Of course testing homogeneity of variance means comparin gthe sample variances of the two groups. I agree with gung's answer completely.

Comment: @gung, you don't need homogeneity of variance to do a two sample $t$-test, do you?

Comment: @Macro, if you don't have equality of variance then you should use the [Satterthwaite-Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation) correction for the degrees of freedom of the [t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test).

Comment: @gung, so, in this special case of regression, lack of homogeneity of variance is an easily remedied problem (+1,btw).

Comment: It is possible that checking the pooled residuals will give the wrong impression. The correctly stated assumption is that the conditional distributions of Y are normal for all X. It is possible that all conditional distributions are non-normal, yet the combined distribution of the residuals is close to (or even exactly) normal. One example occurs with ordinal Y (say 1,2,3,4,5): the pooled residuals are continuous-looking, may pass the normality tests, and may have q-q plots that appear perfectly normal. Yet obviously normality is violated because of discreteness.