# Units of emmeans output?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

I have values of relative humidity on a scale of 0 to 1 (e.g., 0.9 = 90% RH). I also have two cities (A or B). My model is as follows:

```
mod <- glm(rh ~ city, family = quasibinomial)
```

I plug my model into emmeans:

```
emmeans(mod, pairwise~city)
```

I get this from the emmeans output:

```
> emmeans(mod, pairwise~city)
$emmeans
city    emmean         SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
A     1.727851 0.01619215 Inf  1.696115  1.759587
B     5.688672 0.26446690 Inf  5.170326  6.207018

Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
contrast   estimate        SE  df z.ratio p.value
A - B      -3.960821 0.2649621 Inf -14.949  <.0001
```

I then predict back on the data-scale to get the mean city RH difference, and present these as means and 95% CIs.

[image: see here]

My questions are these:

1) How can I possibly have values above 1? Relative humidity can't be higher than 100%, so how do I have means of 5.7 and 1.7?

2) If these values are not RH, what are the units of measure? For example, I want to report the mean and 95% confidence intervals, how would I do so? It feels wrong to just say, "the difference in relative humidity between city A and B is 3.96"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your output says

```
Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale.
```

So to get them on response scale, you need to pass them through inverse of the logit link function.

You can recall, that generalized linear models [are defined in terms of](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190763/how-to-decide-which-glm-family-to-use/303592#303592) linear predictor, that is passed through [link function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259683/understand-link-function-in-generalized-linear-model/259688#259688), to predict mean of some distribution. In case of [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039), we use [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) link function, i.e.

$$
\operatorname{logit}(p) = \log(\tfrac{p}{1-p}) = \eta = X\beta
$$

So the untransformed values returned by logistic regression [are log odds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133623/help-me-understand-adjusted-odds-ratio-in-logistic-regression/133633#133633). To transform them to probabilities, the linear predictor $\eta = X\beta$ is passed through inverse of the logit function, i.e. logistic function

$$
E(Y|X) = p = \operatorname{logit}^{-1}(\eta) = \frac{\exp(\eta)}{\exp(\eta)+1}
$$

*TL;DR* so to transform the values returned by the function you mention (I am not familiar with this package), you need to use the logistic function, to get the probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim. So the logit scale is a probability? After doing some reading, I'm still confused as to what my numbers actually represent. And I'm still confused as to how I would pass them through the inverse of the logit link function. Is this like back-transforming data? I'm sorry for being obtuse.

Comment: @NoraaZamliy no, the opposite. I'll edit my answer for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Do

```r
emm <- emmeans(mod, "city", type = "response")
emm
pairs(emm)
```

The comparisons will be odds ratios.

You can also do `plot(emm)` to see the CIs on the response scale.

It’s all documented. See `vignette("basics")`, `vignette("transformations")`, and `?summary.emmGrid`

Comment: So if my emmeans odds ratio output is 0.106 for the city A/city B contrast, does that mean there is a 10.6% difference in humidity between city A and B? I'm so confused. Please help.

Comment: No. The odds of something equals p/(1-p): the probably of occurring divided by the probability of not occurring. So the odds ratio you refer to is [pA/(1-pA)] / [pB/(1-pB)]. Note that odds equal to 1 (“even odds”) is equivalent to p equals 1/2.