# is "multivariable linear regression" the same as logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, linear

I am new to machine learning and I am simultaneously studying linear and logistic regression. Logistic regression is when there is one dependent variable and there may be more than one independent variable

Multivariable linear regression attempts to find a linear relationship between multiple variables where every independent variable x must have a dependent variable y.

Can anyone tell me the difference between the two?

Comment: Logistic regression involves a binary response. Linear regression does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In linear regression, you predict the target variable $y$ using a model that is based on a linear function of the predictors $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_k$

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_2 + \beta_2 X_2 + \dots + \beta_k X_k + \varepsilon
$$

In logistic regression, the target variable is binary, and you are trying to predict probability of "success" $p(y=1)$ using a linear predictor $\eta$ *passed through the [link function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259683/understand-link-function-in-generalized-linear-model/259688#259688)* $\sigma$ (logistic function is [the most common choice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models)), i.e.

$$
\eta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_2 + \beta_2 X_2 + \dots + \beta_k X_k \\
p(y=1) = \sigma(\eta)
$$

So both can be functions of a single, or multiple variables. The differences are that the target variable differs (values on real line vs binary), and logistic regression, as other [generalized linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model), uses a link function.

Answer (score 2):

In multiple linear regression (MLR), you still have one dependent variable, and the relation is as follows:
$$y_i=\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_ix_i+\epsilon$$
In logistic regression (LR), what you predict is a probability, namely the class posterior, and is bounded unlike MLR output. They're similar in the sense that they both use linear combination of features. The probability of class 1 is estimated as follows in LR:
$$p_i=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\sum\beta_i x_i)}}$$

So, LR is actually taking $\text{logit}$ of MLR output.