# Compare the variances of several groups seprately

Tags: regression, anova, variance

I asked this question:

[Compare the variances of several groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83712/compare-the-variances-of-several-groups?noredirect=1#comment164193_83712)

The Levene's method  only test all groups. How can I identify the groups that have a different variances?

Comment: Levene's test is based on ANOVA. Why not approach it in the same way as pairwise means comparisons in ANOVA?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using some magic black box tests, do it rigorously. You can find the answer in excelent article from Larry Bretthorst, "On The Difference In Means".

http://bayes.wustl.edu/glb/diff.pdf

Unlike what the title says, the paper is also about the difference and the magnitude of difference between stabdard deviations of two samples.