# Meta-analysis of standard deviations

Tags: standard-deviation, meta-analysis

Does anybody know whether it's possible to conduct a meta-analysis, outcome of interest being difference in standard deviations between two medical interventions, instead of the difference in mean? 
We are assessing continuous variables from RCTs.

Comment: Variances should be quite doable. The variance is the actual parameter of a normal distribution, not the SD. You could always take the square root of the final values for interpretability.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestions how I could do this using software packages as R or Stata? Standard meta-analyses use means and inverse of variances for weighting. How would that work for a meta-analysis where the variance is the outcome of interest.

Comment: @P.Jansen it doesn’t matter if it’s variance or standard deviation. At the end of the day, you’re gonna have to assume normal distribution to conduct aggregate meta-analysis. Std. Devs and variances all converge to normal distributions in large samples.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility you can look into is comparing the variance between your two medical interventions in each study using Levene's Test or Brown-Forsythe test. Then you can combine the p-values from each study using Stoufer's test (allows weighting) or Fisher's test (harder to weight).

For more on comparing variances look here 
([Levene vs Brown-Forsythe](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83712/compare-the-variances-of-several-groups)) and for more on combining p-values look here ([Fisher's and Stouffer's Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method)).

Comment: If the OP has extracted the variances from the primary articles I do not see how s/he can do either Levene or Brown-Forsythe as they require the raw data which s/he will not have.

Comment: The indicated reference contains methodology on how to use summary measures of means and variances to produce weighted Levene statistics. Have not come across Brown-Forsythe methods. See the following: Deng, W. Q., et al. (2014). Meta-analysis of SNPs involved in variance heterogeneity using Levene's test for equal variances. European Journal of Human Genetics : EJHG, 22(3), 427–430)